# resampled time using scipy.signal.resample

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, resampling

I have a signal that is not sampled equidistant; for further processing it needs to be. I thought that scipy.signal.resample would do it, but I do not understand its behavior.

The signal is in y, corresponding time in x.
The resampled is expected in yy, with all corresponding time in xx. Does anyone know what I do wrong or how to achieve what I need?

This code does not work: xx is not time:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9])
y = np.cos(-x**2/4.0)
num=50
z=signal.resample(y, num, x, axis=0, window=None)
yy=z[0]
xx=z[1]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xx,yy)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 14):

Even when you give the `x` coordinates (which corresponds to the `t` argument), [`resample`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) assumes that the sampling is uniform.

Consider using one of the univariate interpolators in [`scipy.interpolate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html).

For example, this script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9])
y = np.cos(-x**2/4.0)

f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)

num = 50
xx = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num)
yy = f(xx)

plt.plot(x,y, 'bo-')
plt.plot(xx,yy, 'g.-')
plt.show()
```

generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Check the docstring of [`interp1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) for options to control the interpolation, and also check out the other interpolation classes.

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I tried a few of the interpolation techniques implemented in numpy. The time aspect works, but the signal constructed by .resample is much better (due to the nature of the source). I will search the scipy repository to see if I can find one that reconstructs with characteristics similar to .resample.

Comment: @frits what was your final conclusion here? I am having the same question