# Resampling an irregular distributed 1-D signal in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resampling

I've a nx2 `ndarray` which represent a height profile of the form h(x), with `x` being a non-negative real number and `h(x)` the height value in x. The x-values are irregular distributed, meaning:
`x[i] - x[i - 1] != x[i + 1] - x[i]`
I would like to take my array and create a new one with evenly spaced x-values with the corresponding heights. The distance between the x-values can be any positive number. Is there an efficient way to do something like this using `numpy`?

Comment: Here's one approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889501/resampled-time-using-scipy-signal-resample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Warren Weckesser's comment, the answer is using `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`