# How to specify the last index explicitly to np.ufunc.reduceat

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

Say I have an array

```
data = np.arange(6)
```

I want to find the sum of the entire array and the second half using [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).<sup>1</sup>

If I do it like this:

```
np.add.reduceat(data, [0, 6, 3])[::2]
```

I immediately get an error

```
IndexError: index 6 out-of-bounds in add.reduceat [0, 6)
```

If I do it like this

```
np.add.reduceat(data, [0, 5, 3])[::2]
```

I get the wrong answer (10 should be 15):

```
array([10, 12])
```

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to mask the locations where the last index is necessary, subtract 1 from them, and then add the last element back in there:

```
index = np.array([0, 6, 3])
mask = (index == data.size)
index[mask] -= 1
result = np.add.reduceat(data, index)
# Mask is shifted back by one because it's the previous element that needs to be updated
result[:-1][mask[1:]] += data[-1]
```

Then `result[::2]` gives the desired answer. This looks like a giant kludge for something that I would expect to be an elegant one-liner (and faster than this).

---

<sup>1</sup> I am *fully* aware that there are better ways to do this. This is just a contrived example for purposes of illustration. The real problem for this question originated with an attempt to solve [numpy: fast regularly-spaced average for large numbers of line segments / points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52312513/2988730).

Comment: How about `np.add.reduceat(np.add.reduceat(data, [0, len(data)-1, len(data)//2]),[0,2])`?

Comment: @Divakar. Nevermind, I misread the parens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used `reduceat` much, but it looks like you can only have one open ended range, one `add to the end`.

One way around that is to pad the array (yes, I do normally rail against using `np.append` :)  ):

```
In [165]: np.add.reduceat(np.append(x,0),[0,6,3])
Out[165]: array([15,  0, 12])
```

or with a full pairing of ranges:

```
In [166]: np.add.reduceat(np.append(x,0),[0,6,3,6])
Out[166]: array([15,  0, 12,  0])
```

I omitted the usual [::2] to clarify what is going on.

Comment: I know that it's traditional to wait before accepting, but this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Especially since the negative increment is clearly defined in this case.

Comment: In case you were wondering what I ended up using this for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52320926/2988730

Comment: I was writing a github issue when I found this answer. Why isn't this considered a bug? Appending additional elements works, but I see no reason to exclude [`indices[i] >= len(array)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html).The `=` looks to me like a *careless mistake* for slices.

Comment: I think there are open issues in GitHub regarding this https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/834 and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/835